# SQL query that returns tag with space and no space simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to return query WHERE Variable LIKE "Test%This" - meaning the query returns when variable is "Test This" and "TestThis".

In other words, the query returns all values where Test This are back to back, regardless if there is a space or not.

Comment: `%` Matches any number of characters, even zero characters, try removing it

Comment: Do you want to return the value that has only space

Comment: If u what to search only one single space use "_" underscore instead of %

Comment: I want to return both zero space and one space.

Comment: I have include that and in post. Plz check

Comment: Why there are two tags (MySQL and SQL Server)?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
WHERE Variable RLIKE 'Test ?This'
```

Answer (score 1):

A space, when it's in the middle of a string, has no special meaning, i.e. you could very well have replaced the space in your requirements with any other single character – it would have made no difference for the problem, in the sense that there is no solution for it in terms of a single LIKE predicate, because no pattern supported by LIKE can match both `Test This` and `TestThis`.

So, your options are:

1. Go platform-specific and use [@GOTO 0's RLIKE suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148735/297408) for MySQL and an external solution for RegExp support for SQL Server.
2. Abandon the idea of a single condition and match against each value individually. This option will be platform-independent and has variations:

   - using `OR` (this was first suggested, albeit syntactically incorrectly, by @Szymon, who deleted the answer after being voted down):

     ```
     WHERE Variable = 'Test This' OR Variable = 'TestThis'
     ```
   - using `IN`:

     ```
     WHERE Variable IN ('Test This', 'TestThis')
     ```
   - using `UNION ALL` (suggested by @Chris Lively in a comment to @Szymon's deleted answer):

     ```
     ... /* some query */
     WHERE Variable = 'Test This'

     UNION ALL

     ... /* same query */
     WHERE Variable = 'TestThis'
     ```

Pick one that suits you most (or displeases you least).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in SQL server

```
from msdn :
_ (underscore) : Any single character.
 Example : WHERE au_fname LIKE '_ean' finds all four-letter first names that end with ean (Dean, Sean, and so on).

Where columnnam like 'Test_This'
```